# Problem building PyGTK on CentOS

Tags: python, pygtk, pygobject

I am trying to build PyGTK on CentOS for a non-standard Python (2.6, vs the out-of-the-box 2.4). It requires that I first build pygobject. pygobject-2.18.0 fails at the configure step. The error messages is as follows:

```
checking for GLIB - version >= 2.14.0... no
*** Could not run GLIB test program, checking why...
*** The test program failed to compile or link. See the file config.log for the
*** exact error that occured. This usually means GLIB is incorrectly installed.
configure: error: maybe you want the pygobject-2-4 branch?
```

I have downloaded, built and successfully installed glib.

The config.log file contains the following output:

```
conftest.c:27:18: error: glib.h: No such file or directory
conftest.c: In function 'main':
conftest.c:33: error: 'glib_major_version' undeclared (first use in this function)
conftest.c:33: error: (Each undeclared identifier is reported only once
conftest.c:33: error: for each function it appears in.)
conftest.c:33: error: 'glib_minor_version' undeclared (first use in this function)
conftest.c:33: error: 'glib_micro_version' undeclared (first use in this function)
configure:13844: $? = 1
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like your glib version is not up to date.

In gentoo, following versions apply in PyGTK 2.16.0:

- glib 2.8.0
- pygobject-2.16.1
- pycairo 2.0.1

Comment: Thanks for replying, @iElectric. We eventually gave up and moved to Ubuntu Server, which makes this as simple as `apt-get install...`

Comment: same problem here - except I can't move to other OS. bummer.